# re2 gcc failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, gcc, compiler-errors, anaconda

I am aware of the many different questions regarding the 'gcc failed with exit status 1' posts. However, unfortunately, I have tried all of the solutions on much of the posts I have read, with little success.

So, although I know it's a long shot, I was wondering if anyone may notice something within this stack trace, or have any different ideas regarding this issue.

```
    gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/chase/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c src/re2.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/re2.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    src/re2.cpp:201:29: fatal error: re2/stringpiece.h: No such file or directory
     #include "re2/stringpiece.h"
                                 ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/chase/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-auz1u37m/re2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-nlt6yjcc-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-auz1u37m/re2/
```

Comment: Do you have a `stringpiece.h` file in your project? Where is it located?

Comment: There's no stack trace anywhere, just an error message saying that the header file wasn't found.

Comment: @Barmar I tried looking for that file but was unable to find it.  I tried installing using `pip`, `easy_install`, `apt-get install python-re2`, and the `setup.py` from github source.  All of it provides the same error.  I don't believe the source code just doesn't include one of it's dependencies or more people would have issues, but I can't tell if it's python vs anaconda issues or something else

Comment: I ended up installing sw-re2 which is a copy of re2 for python 3 which worked and was able to understand by pip